# Amazon min-width Rule And 980px Width on iPhone 6

Tags: css, iphone, google-chrome, mobile

Amazon desktop website has min-width:1000px rule on its subelements like header etc. but it fits into the iPhone 6 viewport (which is 980px wide) without any horizontal scrollbars when I do "Request Desktop Site" on Chrome. How do they do it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, they're not doing anything special to allow that - Chrome is just "zooming out" to the minimum width of the page (1000px) by default in Desktop Site mode.

Comment: @JonUleis But when I try to put a 1000px div inside an empty body, it shows the scrollbar. Why is that?

Comment: I don't know. I just created a CodePen with only this code, then set Chrome (desktop) to render as an iPhone 6 Plus, and there's no scrollbar: `<div style="width: 1000px; height: 30px; background: blue;"></div>`

Comment: @JonUleis It seems to show on an actual iPhone though.